# MySQL GROUP BY on a calculated value gives an error - using other values produces unexpected results

Tags: mysql, sql

This query returns all 23 of these music.id's:
39,64,1327,1608,1644,1657,1666,1676,1681,1686,1691,1711,1726,1730,1811,1851,2346,2440,2967,2968,2996,2998,3110

But... I want to group on a calculated value, then group by category (since 'name' is unique to each record and category isn't)

```
SELECT 
    music.id, 
    music.name AS name, 
    music.filename, 
    music.url_name, 
    music.file_path_high, 
    music.filesize, 
    music.categories AS category, 
    music.duration, 
    music.folder AS folder, 
SUM(active0.weight) + SUM(active1.weight) AS total_weight
FROM (music)
INNER JOIN linked_tags AS active0 
    ON active0.track_id = music.id AND active0.tag_id = 1
INNER JOIN linked_tags AS active1 
    ON active1.track_id = music.id AND active1.tag_id = 11
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY total_weight DESC
```

But... when I try to GROUP BY `total_weight` I get an error (it says I "can't group on total_weight"). Can I not GROUP BY a calculated value? Also, if I try to GROUP BY any other value, the results that are returned are unique for that GROUP BY parameter, so depending on the parameter, I may get 0 results. GROUP BY 'music.categories' for instance only returns 7 items, 7 items all with different categories. Each item's 'name' value is unique, so it really can't group anything anyway, so I figured that by grouping by 'categories' would at least group them by their like integers of a category they belong to, but that's not what I'm seeing.

My table structure is like so:

```
//music table
ID  name                categories  
1   Hopeful 02          1
2   Organic 01b         3
3   Organic 01c         3
4   Instrumental 01     8

// linked_tags table
track_id    tag_id  weight
1           1       3
2           2       4
2           3       5
2           1       2
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your question describes **how** you are trying to do something, not **what** information you are trying to retrieve. Perhaps you could include sample data and your intended output?

Comment: I'm trying to get all music tracks from 1 table that have tag_id's tied to them from another table. Each tag_id has a weight attribute, which I want to add up all of the 'active' tags for that music track and sort them by weight, highest to lowest, then group the ones with the same category within those weights. Check out http://search.ascheandspencer.com - if you choose 2 tags from above, I have it outputting the selected tracks by weight, but I want tracks with similar names to appear together (Acoustic 2b and Acoustic 2c for example)

Comment: I think I understand - I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood what `group by` does in SQL - it ensures that only one row is returned for each combination of groups.

In order to retrieve multiple rows in a specific order, you need to use `order by` - like so:

```
SELECT 
    music.id, 
    music.name AS name, 
    music.filename, 
    music.url_name, 
    music.file_path_high, 
    music.filesize, 
    music.categories AS category, 
    music.duration, 
    music.folder AS folder, 
    SUM(active.weight) AS total_weight
FROM (music)
INNER JOIN linked_tags AS active
    ON active.track_id = music.id AND active.tag_id in (1, 11)
GROUP BY music.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT active.tag_id)=2
ORDER BY category, total_weight DESC
```

Comment: So, this would be an added bonus for me, but is there a way to order by total_weight, then randomly by name but make sure that ones with similar names are grouped together? This is so it doesn't appear alphabetical within weight, but tracks like Acoustic 1b and Acoustic 1c stick together?

Comment: @jpea: I can't think of any way to sort randomly by name but have similar names stick together - is there a reason why you wouldn't want to sort by music name within category and weight?

Comment: yeah, the client just wants it to feel more random, like things were hand picked for the viewer (which collective weight provides), but they are requesting something more granular.

Comment: @jpea: You could fake it by adding something like `REVERSE(left(music.name, CHARINDEX(' ',music.name)))` to the end of the `ORDER BY` clause - this would sort by the first word of the name spelt *backwards*, so it should be less obvious that it is sorting by name.

Comment: Any idea if CHARINDEX is available in MySQL? I'm getting an error and can't find documentation on it for that platform

Comment: nevermind - changed it to REVERSE(left(name, POSITION(" " IN "music.name"))) for mysql and it worked great - thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't group by an aggregate function. It has to calculate the sum using the group and it gets the group using the sum, it's a catch 22 situation.

You may have meant to group on `active0.weight + active1.weight`

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT 
    music.id,
    music.name AS name, 
    music.filename, 
    music.url_name, 
    music.file_path_high, 
    music.filesize, 
    music.categories AS category, 
    music.duration, 
    music.folder AS folder,
    total_weights.weight as total_weight
FROM music
JOIN (SELECT 
        music.categories as category, 
        SUM(active0.weight + active1.weight) as weight
    FROM (music)
    INNER JOIN linked_tags AS active0 
      ON active0.track_id = music.id AND active0.tag_id = 1
    INNER JOIN linked_tags AS active1 
      ON active1.track_id = music.id AND active1.tag_id = 11
    GROUP BY music.categories
) total_weights
ON music.categories = total_weights.category
INNER JOIN linked_tags AS active0
  ON active0.track_id = music.id AND active0.tag_id = 1
INNER JOIN linked_tags AS active1 
  ON active1.track_id = music.id AND active1.tag_id = 11
ORDER BY total_weight DESC
```

Comment: seems logical, though I get an "invalid use of group function" error. Any idea on why using GROUP BY music.categories returns 7 results? They are all unique results, but I want it to return all results that match, then just group the ones together that belong to the same category.

Comment: -1 You can't group by an aggregate function - this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Taking out the comma after total_weights.weight as total_weight returned results, though now it returns 1571 results. Is there any way to tailor it so it's a 'subtractive' search so it only returns entries with tags where a tag_id AND tag_id of 11 both exist in the tags table?

Comment: @MarkBannister's answer is probably what you want, much cleaner

Comment: thanks for walking me through it PinnyM - Mark's answer was the one that ultimately worked, but yours led me in a good direction to make my sql skills better :)